# JAXB unmarshalling - reader cannot be null

Tags: java, apache-camel, jaxb, integration

I want to retrieve some data from JMS, filter them and send them to REST server. When I unmarshal those data I get an error:

> java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: reader can not be null
> at com.sun.xml.bind.v2.runtime.unmarshaller.UnmarshallerImpl.unmarshal0(UnmarshallerImpl.java:370)
> at com.sun.xml.bind.v2.runtime.unmarshaller.UnmarshallerImpl.unmarshal(UnmarshallerImpl.java:356)
> at org.apache.camel.converter.jaxb.JaxbDataFormat.unmarshal(JaxbDataFormat.java:300)
> at org.apache.camel.support.processor.UnmarshalProcessor.process(UnmarshalProcessor.java:76)
> at org.apache.camel.processor.errorhandler.RedeliveryErrorHandler$SimpleTask.run(RedeliveryErrorHandler.java:471)
> at org.apache.camel.impl.engine.DefaultReactiveExecutor$Worker.schedule(DefaultReactiveExecutor.java:193)
> at org.apache.camel.impl.engine.DefaultReactiveExecutor.scheduleMain(DefaultReactiveExecutor.java:64)
> at org.apache.camel.processor.Pipeline.process(Pipeline.java:184)
> at org.apache.camel.impl.engine.CamelInternalProcessor.process(CamelInternalProcessor.java:399)
> at org.apache.camel.impl.engine.DefaultAsyncProcessorAwaitManager.process(DefaultAsyncProcessorAwaitManager.java:83)
> at org.apache.camel.support.AsyncProcessorSupport.process(AsyncProcessorSupport.java:41)
> at org.apache.camel.component.jms.EndpointMessageListener.onMessage(EndpointMessageListener.java:132)
> at org.springframework.jms.listener.AbstractMessageListenerContainer.doInvokeListener(AbstractMessageListenerContainer.java:736)
> at org.springframework.jms.listener.AbstractMessageListenerContainer.invokeListener(AbstractMessageListenerContainer.java:696)
> at org.springframework.jms.listener.AbstractMessageListenerContainer.doExecuteListener(AbstractMessageListenerContainer.java:674)
> at org.springframework.jms.listener.AbstractPollingMessageListenerContainer.doReceiveAndExecute(AbstractPollingMessageListenerContainer.java:318)
> at org.springframework.jms.listener.AbstractPollingMessageListenerContainer.receiveAndExecute(AbstractPollingMessageListenerContainer.java:257)
> at org.springframework.jms.listener.DefaultMessageListenerContainer$AsyncMessageListenerInvoker.invokeListener(DefaultMessageListenerContainer.java:1237)
> at org.springframework.jms.listener.DefaultMessageListenerContainer$AsyncMessageListenerInvoker.executeOngoingLoop(DefaultMessageListenerContainer.java:1227)
> at org.springframework.jms.listener.DefaultMessageListenerContainer$AsyncMessageListenerInvoker.run(DefaultMessageListenerContainer.java:1120)
> at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1128)
> at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:628)
> at java.base/java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:829)
> 14:46:44.399 [Camel (camel-1) thread #1 - JmsConsumer[MATERIALS_ENRICHED]] DEBUG org.apache.camel.processor.Pipeline - Message exchange has failed: so breaking out of pipeline for exchange: Exchange[3917DB1BA45A384-0000000000000013] Exception: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: reader can not be null
> 14:46:44.399 [Camel (camel-1) thread #1 - JmsConsumer[MATERIALS_ENRICHED]] WARN org.apache.camel.component.jms.EndpointMessageListener - Execution of JMS message listener failed. Caused by: [org.apache.camel.RuntimeCamelException - java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: reader can not be null  ]

I found out the reader which is null is created in unmarshal method in JaxbDataFormat class:

```
public Object unmarshal(Exchange exchange, InputStream stream) throws IOException {
        try {
            XMLStreamReader xmlReader;
            if (this.needFiltering(exchange)) {
                xmlReader = (XMLStreamReader)this.typeConverter.convertTo(XMLStreamReader.class, exchange, this.createNonXmlFilterReader(exchange, stream));
            } else {
                xmlReader = (XMLStreamReader)this.typeConverter.convertTo(XMLStreamReader.class, exchange, stream);
            }
            ...
        }
}
```

I suspect I miss something in my pom.xml file:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0"
         xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
         xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>

    <groupId>com.release11</groupId>
    <artifactId>toRest</artifactId>
    <version>1.0-SNAPSHOT</version>
    <packaging>jar</packaging>

    <properties>
        <maven.compiler.source>11</maven.compiler.source>
        <maven.compiler.target>11</maven.compiler.target>
    </properties>

    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.camel</groupId>
            <artifactId>camel-core</artifactId>
            <version>3.16.0</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.camel</groupId>
            <artifactId>camel-jackson</artifactId>
            <version>3.16.0</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.camel</groupId>
            <artifactId>camel-jdbc</artifactId>
            <version>3.16.0</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.camel</groupId>
            <artifactId>camel-jsonpath</artifactId>
            <version>3.16.0</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.commons</groupId>
            <artifactId>commons-dbcp2</artifactId>
            <version>2.8.0</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>mysql</groupId>
            <artifactId>mysql-connector-java</artifactId>
            <version>8.0.28</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.logging.log4j</groupId>
            <artifactId>log4j-api</artifactId>
            <version>2.17.2</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.logging.log4j</groupId>
            <artifactId>log4j-core</artifactId >
            <version>2.17.2</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.activemq</groupId>
            <artifactId>activemq-client</artifactId>
            <version>5.16.2</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.activemq</groupId>
            <artifactId>activemq-camel</artifactId>
            <version>5.16.4</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.camel</groupId>
            <artifactId>camel-jaxb</artifactId>
            <version>3.16.0</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.camel</groupId>
            <artifactId>camel-jaxb-starter</artifactId>
            <version>2.25.4</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.camel</groupId>
            <artifactId>camel-jms</artifactId>
            <version>3.15.0</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.activemq</groupId>
            <artifactId>activemq-broker</artifactId>
            <version>5.16.4</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>javax.xml.bind</groupId>
            <artifactId>jaxb-api</artifactId>
            <version>2.3.1</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.sun.xml.bind</groupId>
            <artifactId>jaxb-impl</artifactId>
            <version>2.3.1</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.sun.xml.messaging.saaj</groupId>
            <artifactId>saaj-impl</artifactId>
            <version>1.5.1</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.fasterxml.jackson.jaxrs</groupId>
            <artifactId>jackson-jaxrs-xml-provider</artifactId>
            <version>2.13.2</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>commons-validator</groupId>
            <artifactId>commons-validator</artifactId>
            <version>1.7</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.camel</groupId>
            <artifactId>camel-undertow</artifactId>
            <version>3.16.0</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.camel</groupId>
            <artifactId>camel-servlet</artifactId>
            <version>3.16.0</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>javax.servlet</groupId>
            <artifactId>javax.servlet-api</artifactId>
            <version>3.1.0</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.camel</groupId>
            <artifactId>camel-servlet-starter</artifactId>
            <version>3.0.0-RC3</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.camel</groupId>
            <artifactId>camel-jackson-starter</artifactId>
            <version>3.0.0-RC3</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.camel</groupId>
            <artifactId>camel-openapi-java</artifactId>
            <version>3.16.0</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.camel</groupId>
            <artifactId>camel-undertow</artifactId>
            <version>3.16.0</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.camel</groupId>
            <artifactId>camel-support</artifactId>
            <version>3.16.0</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.camel</groupId>
            <artifactId>camel-log</artifactId>
            <version>3.16.0</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.camel</groupId>
            <artifactId>camel-netty-http</artifactId>
            <version>3.16.0</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.camel</groupId>
            <artifactId>camel-http</artifactId>
            <version>3.16.0</version>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>
    <build>
        <resources>
            <resource>
                <directory>${project.basedir}/src/main/resources</directory>
            </resource>
        </resources>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-assembly-plugin</artifactId>
                <executions>
                    <execution>
                        <phase>package</phase>
                        <goals>
                            <goal>single</goal>
                        </goals>
                        <configuration>
                            <archive>
                                <manifest>
                                    <mainClass>
                                        com.release11.OutputAdapter
                                    </mainClass>
                                </manifest>
                            </archive>
                            <descriptorRefs>
                                <descriptorRef>jar-with-dependencies</descriptorRef>
                            </descriptorRefs>
                        </configuration>
                    </execution>
                </executions>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>
</project>
```

And here's my code of the integration:

```
public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
        PropertiesReader properties = new PropertiesReader("properties.properties");

        ActiveMQConnectionFactory connectionFactory = new ActiveMQConnectionFactory("tcp://" + properties.getProperty("activemq-host"));
        Connection connection = connectionFactory.createConnection();
        connection.start();
        CamelContext context = new DefaultCamelContext();
        context.addComponent("activemq", JmsComponent.jmsComponentAutoAcknowledge(connectionFactory));

        context.addRoutes(new RouteBuilder() {
            @Override
            public void configure() throws Exception {
                JAXBContext jaxbContext = JAXBContext.newInstance(ObjectFactory.class);
                JaxbDataFormat xmlDataFormat = new JaxbDataFormat(jaxbContext);

                restConfiguration()
                        .component("undertow")
                        .host(properties.getProperty("rest-host"))
                        .port(properties.getProperty("rest-port"))
                        .bindingMode(RestBindingMode.auto);

                from("activemq:topic:MATERIALS_ENRICHED?clientId=420&durableSubscriptionName=foo2")
                        .unmarshal(xmlDataFormat)
                        .filter(simple("${body.type} in 'A1,A2,A3'"))
                        .bean(JsonMapper.class, "process")
                        .delay(20000)
                        .process(exchange -> exchange.getIn().setHeader(Exchange.CONTENT_TYPE, constant("application/json")))
                        .to("rest:post:materials");
            }
        });
        context.start();
    }
```

Can you please give me a hint what is wrong? I'm running out of ideas what to try. Please help me.

EDIT: In intellij this works just fine, the problem appears when I pack the integration in JAR.

Comment: Have you tried providing `JAXBContext.newInstance` the type you're expecting to receive from the topic instead of `ObjectFactory.class` ? e.g `JAXBContext jaxbContext = JAXBContext.newInstance(MaterialsEnriched.class);`

Comment: Yes, I get the same outcome.

Comment: The `reader can not be null` exception sounds like Jaxb cannot create reader for the body-type provided. You could try convert the body to string before marshal and maybe also check exchange contents with  `.to("log:loggerName?showAll=true")` to see exchange contents.

Comment: @PasiÖsterman I tried this. Data are pulled from ActiveMQ correctly, log shows the XML of the message as it should.

Answer (score 0):

Okay, I've got it. I was running fat jar, when I had created a thin jar and then ran it it worked.